# Online portfolio return calculator

Tags: united-states, etf, calculation, portfolio

Is there a online calculator where I can punch in ETFs that I want in my portfolio and it shows the return over time?

I want to add GLD, VOO, VGT to see what my return would have been and then possibly replace VGT with some other ETF and see if the return is different.

Comment: Close votes?  How is determining performance of investments not about Personal Finance?

Comment: @BobBaerker - I am abstaining. But I suspect this appears to be a product/service recommendation. It would be answered with a link to a site, which can easily break.

Comment: This will be closed as off-topic (product/service recommendation) but check out https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/backtest-portfolio

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I appreciate the feedback but in the here and now, the OP gets a useful  answer to his question (mine and the one from Chris Rea) and if the TWO links don't break, future readers can obtain the same guidance to a solution to their question.  Over and out.

Comment: @BobBaerker These kinds of questions tend to attract spam and astroturfing.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea -FWIW,  I think that the policy  should be to delete comments and answers that are spam and astroturfing rather than deleting questions that 'might' attract spam and astroturfing.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the link. If you can add that as answer I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like Sharesight.com, it lets you track up to 10 funds and splits things out nicely by equity gain, currency gain and dividend gains.

Yahoo portfolios are also okay, but they don’t show dividends.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [DRIP calculator](https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/) that will allow you to pick a time frame.  It will give you the separate stats for reinvestment of dividends and without reinvestment.

Comment: LOL.  Down voting a DRIP calculator.